# Unable to add HTTPS on subdomain

Tags: debian, ssl, lets-encrypt

It's been 5 days and I'm becoming crazy on this.

I'm trying to install a Let's Encrypt certificate on a subdomain that I've created and I can't get it working.

Here are my .conf files in sites-available :

```
test.com.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName test.com
ServerAlias www.test.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride All
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.test.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

So this one works and I have a `test-le-ssl.conf` created in sites-available.

And here is my `whydoesntitwork.test.com.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/whydoesntitwork
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/whydoesntitwork>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride All
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

When I run ./letsencrypt-auto or add -d test.com -d whydoesntitwork.com, it asks me if I want to renew or try to reinstall. I reinstall cause I don't want to be locked out (they say that we can do ~5-7 times per week).

The error I get when trying to put SSL on whydoesntitwork is :

```
The selected vhost would conflict with other HTTPS VirtualHosts within Apache. Please select another vhost or add ServerNames to your configuration.
VirtualHost not able to be selected.
```

I've already added the two domains on `/etc/apache2/hosts` as below :

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
(myip)        test.com   test
(myip)        whydoesntitwork.test.com        whydoesntitwork
```

What am I doing wrong ?

EDIT : added apache's version

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
Server built:   Sep 21 2017 20:51:54
```

Thank you

Comment: What version of apache?  If you are using 2.2, then you need to set the NameVirtualHost directive.  Also, I don't see a ServerName directive in the second configuration.

Comment: Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
Server built:   Sep 21 2017 20:51:54

Sorry I didn't think about that. I add it to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Apache 2.2, you will need to set NameVirtualHost

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Also, you appear to be missing the ServerName directive in the 2nd configuration.

Lastly, have you enable the configuration that is in sites-available?

Comment: Thank you @JohnA, I don't know how I have forgotten that. As soon as I've added the ServerName it worked

Comment: Great.  Glad it worked for you.  Always those little details